# Cant install boot-repair or OS-uninstaller

Tags: dependencies, boot-repair

I could not install boot-repair or OS-uninstaller

"`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: boot-repair : Depends: boot-sav but it is not going to be installed libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libllvm3.5:i386 (>= 1:3.5~+rc3) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`"

"`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libllvm3.5:i386 (>= 1:3.5~+rc3) but it is not going to be installed os-uninstaller : Depends: boot-sav but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` "

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 19.10 Live (USB/CD) causes a similar issue, with a different dependency. The cause is the `universe` repository not being enabled, and the `python` dependency not being found.

This is easily fixed using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

and then attempting to install `boot-repair` again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try its suggestion and use

```
sudo apt-get install -f boot-repair
```

also try

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo ap-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386
```

Then try to re-install

Comment: I have tried all of these options and I get the same unmet dependencies message, how can i just re-install ubuntu?